# Microsoft Bot Framework only allows one session, then stops working until service is restarted

Tags: javascript, c#, botframework

I've a bot set up in Azure and I can only create one conversation which works perfectly. After the first conversation is closed, if I try to open another, it does not work at all. The only way at the moment for me to create another working conversation is to restart the application in Azure which is not a permanent solution.

Has this been experienced by anyone else? Does anyone know how I can possibly debug this as there are no errors appearing in Azure's interface?

Thanks.

Comment: Never seen that. But please add more context: which channel are you using? Can you give us details about your code to see if you are doing something that can cause this behaviour

Comment: Please include your code so we can take a look